# Meme Command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have 2 meme commands in my discord.py bot. I am using the redditeasy api as someone told me that it is faster asyncpraw and praw(which is true).

my Question: Is there any way to randomise the subreddits? What i mean to say is, The api should take a random subreddit from the list of subreddits given, and then pick a random post from that randomly selected subreddit.

I tried doing:

random_sub_list = random.choice['Subreddits here']

and then passing that variable in subreddit but doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#memes


@bot.command(aliases = ['m'])
async def meme(ctx):
  post = redditeasy.AsyncSubreddit(subreddit = 'dankmemes',                              client_id='id here',
                                client_secret = 'secret',
                                user_agent = 'memes')

  postoutput = await post.get_post()

  em2 = discord.Embed(title = f'{postoutput.title}')
  url = postoutput.content
  
  em2.set_image(url = url)
  await ctx.send(embed = em2)


#narutomemes


@bot.command(aliases = ['Nmeme', 'NMEME', 'nm', 'NM', 'Nm'])
async def nmeme(ctx):
  post = redditeasy.AsyncSubreddit(subreddit = 'narutomemes',                              client_id='id here',
                                client_secret = 'secret',
                                user_agent = 'memes')

  postoutput = await post.get_post()

  em3 = discord.Embed(title = f'{postoutput.title}')
  url = postoutput.content
  
  em3.set_image(url = url)
  await ctx.send(embed = em3)
```

Comment: By doesn't work, i mean to say i does not even show any error in terminal, and the command also does not send any meme.

Comment: You can append them to a list using a loop

Comment: `lst = []` | `for sub in this: ` and use `lst.append(sub)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this.

```py
def get_post_from_random_subreddit():
    subreddit_name = random.choice(["dankmemes", "narutomemes"])
    subreddit = redditeasy.AsyncSubreddit(
        subreddit=subreddit_name,
        client_secret="secret",
        user_agent="memes"
    )
    post = asyncio.run(subreddit.get_post())
    return f"{post.title} from {post.subreddit_name}"
```

But without the discord bot and it works perfect. The posts are randomly from the 2 subreddits. I also used your client secret.

Be careful with sharing this secret. Some might abuse it!

Comment: `asyncio.run` should only be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, using it within a synchronous function that will be called more than once is a bad idea, if you're already using `AsyncSubreddit` why not make the whole function asynchronous and await `subreddit.get_post`?

Comment: You see I want it in discord. If it works without the discord bot then, what is the point?

Comment: Also thanks you for reminding me. I actually forgot to remove the I'd amd secret and stuff

Answer (score 1):

i honestly prefer https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/(your subreddit) this will return a random post from ur provided subreddit but the subreddit must have photos, (it will return it as JSON)
this is my current code for meme

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, description='Usage: e!meme')
async def meme(ctx):
    content = get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/dankmemes").text
    data = json.loads(content,)
    meme = discord.Embed(title=data['title'], url=data['postLink'], color = colors.purple, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    meme.set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
    meme.set_footer(text=f'Used by {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.reply(embed=meme)
```

https://github.com/D3vd/Meme_Api this is the docs